# What is faster passing arguments or using static variable in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, static, final

I have to use a variable which will never be changed in method which will be frequently used in many threads. Which of these variants are more efficient?
Variant 1:

```
public class Test {
    private static int myVar;
    public Test(int myVar){
        this.myVar=myVar;
    }

    public void frequentlyUsedMultiThreadMethod(){
        //read myVar
    }
}
```

Variant 2:

```
public class Test {
    public void frequentlyUsedMultiThreadMethod(int myVar){
        //read myVar
    }
}
```

Variant 3:

```
public class Test {
    private final int myVar;
    public Test(int myVar){
        this.myVar=myVar;
    }

    public void frequentlyUsedMultiThreadMethod(){
        //read myVar
    }
}
```

Comment: i would go for variant 3

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you explain why it is more efficient?

Comment: Which is faster, a black car or a red car?

Comment: The red car of course. The black car uses lead paint making it heavier and therefore slower.

Comment: @Kayaman in the multi-threading cases, option one is a black car and a read car driving in opposite directions down the same single line road.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That too. Though you could still try to measure their speed before the inevitable ;)

Comment: If speed really matters that much you could also make the class final (or the method). But in most cases the overall performance change won't be noticable

Comment: This question is underspecified. It is impossible to differentiate the performance of such extremely similar variants until you have specified much more details about the context where it's going to be used, and this is especially true for JIT-compiled runtimes. Finally, after you specify it all, the only meaningful answer will be "you are the only one who can find that out, by careful measurement".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading a single `int`, no matter from what location, is so extremely fast, that you would be hard-pressed to construct a piece of code that demonstrates a meaningful difference in time between the three approaches from your question, let alone finding a difference in arbitrary piece of code. The problem in constructing a benchmark is that the variable never changes, so the compiler would be allowed to read it once per method call, even if `frequentlyUsedMultiThreadMethod` accesses it in a loop.

When this is the case, the best approach is to think what approach reflects the logical use of the data in your program.

- The first approach should be dismissed, because multiple instances set the same static variable. This is confusing when the same value is used, and wrong when multiple values of `myVar` are used for different instances.
- The second approach requires the caller to pass the same variable multiple times, while the value is available at the time of construction. While less confusing than the first approach, this approach is not ideal.
- The third approach shows in code that the value of `myVar` is one per instance, and that it does not change. This is the most logical approach to the situation that you described in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest, clearest and least error prone solution is also the fastest (or fast enough) which is often the case in Java.

Before you worry about speed, you should ask yourself; what is the simplest, clearest and least error prone approach? Passing values via static values is very error prone, esp when you have a multi-threaded application. Don't do it.  The speed is unimportant if your program doesn't work.

However, in this case it is also confusing to use `static` fields. It is not clear to the caller what they must set first.  If you use recursion, this will make your job even harder.

To make matters worse, local variables can be optimised more than static fields. This means static fields are also slower, possibly much slower.

Note: to prevent JIT optimisations JMH uses a "blackhole" for the resulting value to stop code being optimised away, it uses a `static` field to do it.

Option 3 is perhaps best provided the value never changes, esp if you have multiple values, however if the value does change it will be slower as you are adding overhead to create the `Test` object each time, the JIT might not optimise away.

Comment: > to prevent JIT optimisations JMH uses a "blackhole" for the resulting value to stop code being optimised away, it uses a static field to do it.

This statement is not correct. Blackhole is much more complicated than "storing in static field": you have write coalescing, write contention, false sharing, etc. with the naive approach like that. When it doubt, see the source: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/e810ce09937a/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/infra/Blackhole.java

Answer (score 0):

Probably variant 2 might be slightly better, as things can be pulled of the stack there.

But: you should very much more worry on creating a **good** (aka [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))
) design, instead of worrying about such subtleties.

It is **very** hard to understand what the JVM and the just-in-time compiler will do to your input in the very first place.

Meaning: you focus on creating good designs; you avoid outright stupid errors; and that is **good** enough regarding "performance thinking". Anything else is premature optimization.

In other words: you only have performance issues ... if you notice them. And then, you don't guess what is better; you start **profiling** your specific application, to understand where the **real** bottlenecks are at runtime.

Of course, your question is interesting in the "what happens at runtime"; but it is really "not relevant" in guiding your design/implementation decisions. Those need to be driven by a will to create helpful abstractions, and a "model" that really fits your domain. Because those are the things that really matter!

Then you end up with code that other people can understand; and more importantly: that can be changed later on, when you figure what your **real** problems are!

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution, uses less memory, no instances created. you need some business in a method. Data will be stored in the thread stack and reduce the thread context switching which consumes additional time if you reuse threads like ThreadPoolExecutor .
If myVar can be changed for another use cases it is better to add it as argument to the method.

```
public class Test {

    public static void frequentlyUsedMultiThreadMethod(int myVar){
        //read myVar
    }
}
```

Comment: But your static final variable is not initialized.

Comment: Yes for this reason it is declared as public to be initialized from another class and final to prevent changes when thread are started.

Comment: This java code cannot be compiled because final variable have to be initialized.

Comment: Yes after focus you are right because it is static & final.  For this it is maybe better as parameter to the method